# Jenkins hangs at git fetch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I'm a beginner with Jenkins and I'm trying to get it to run some unit tests in my.NET project.

When I run a build it hangs when trying to fetch from the Git repository.

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/name.of.repo
```

I've generated the known hosts and copied the .ssh dir to  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile.ssh as per the jenkins instructions at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin under "Jenkins, GIT plugin and Windows"

I ran ssh git@github.com from the command line and I can successfully authenticate.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably a firewall issue.
You can authenticate to Github using SSH (port 22), so that route is working.
Your job however is trying to access github via https://github.com (port 443) which timeouts.
Try accessing github over ssh by changing the repository url to `git@github.com:account/repository.git` (you can find this URL on the main page of the repo, dropdown 'Choose a clone URL', option 'SSH'.

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks, much appreciated :)

Comment: how about if it is intermittent?  Got any ideas?  The majority of clone operations work fine but some hang forever

Comment: Does the problem appear for all builds/jobs or for specific ones? If it happens incidentally, I suspect it's a netwerk/firewall related issue. When a clone operation hangs, are you able to reach github.com from the Jenkins node? And how about other web sites?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP. SSH credentials are stored in Jenkins and work for many other nodes accessing the same repo. I can ssh into the machine as the Jenkins user and do a `git clone` on the repo using the same SSH repo URL as the Jenkins job (`git@git.com:account/repo.git`).

As a workaround, I set the git credentials in the Jenkins job to `none` for now. I assume that allows it to use the credentials stored locally.

It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to use SSH to access your remote Git repository instead of username & password,you must pay attention to the Timeout Settings for clone and fetch.

**When you have a bad internet connection and a large size of remote repository will cause you clone timeout.**

Go to the project settings:`Source Code Management` -> `Additional Behaviours` -> `Advanced clone behaviours` -> `Timeout (In Minutes) for clone and fetch operations` -> more than 10 minutes.

[image]

And then if you are still have the same problem that the git clone stuck for a long time whether a bad internet connection or a large size of remote repository or not,you can try to use SSH to access your remote Git repository instead of username & password.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative to using SSH is to add this snippet before running any `git` command.

```sh
echo "https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.intuit.com" >> /tmp/gitcredfile
git config --global credential.helper "store --file=/tmp/gitcredfile"
```