# Jenkins job stuck on git fetch in windows10

Tags: git, jenkins

I have setup Jenkins server on windows10 pro and created a GitHub project job in it.

When I build this project, below command will be time out.
I have set the timeout value to be 1 hour but it is still timed out.
So I believe it relates to `git` command on windows.

```
C:\Users\devel\scoop\shims\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/XXX/test.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=60
```

Then I tried to run below command manually through windows command window and it works fine.

```
C:\Users\devel\scoop\shims\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/XXX/test.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

How to solve this issue on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Jenkins hangs at git fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36752453/6309)", it is probably a firewall issue, however it happens only for Jenkins and *not* from the command-line as a user. If Jenkins is running as the system account (instead of a user account), that could be the problem.

Check if using an ssh url works better: `git@github.com`

Regarding the error `Couldn't find remote ref #`, check what command you typed: you don't want to add the # timeout 60 at the end:

```
git fetch ... # timeout 60
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              (wrong)
```

Try:

```
C:\Users\devel\scoop\shims\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/XXX/test.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: sorry I was wrong about the window command. It was not hung actually, instead it return with an error message. I have posted it on the question.

Comment: after remove the # timeout 60 from the command, it works fine in the command window. So I think this is only a comments added by jenkins. But Jenkins job still hang there.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Check with what account your Jenkins slave is running: the system account might have an issue with http connection. Also, would an ssh url work better?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Great! I have edited the answer to make that root cause more visible.